# How do I load (bind) an image to a property in my viewmodel using Prism and MVVM with ViewFirst View Injection?

Tags: wpf, image, prism

Using Prism, MVVM with View First View Injection: Unable to load Image in Module

I am using WPF and Prism in an MVVM pattern using the View First, View Injection pattern.

In my solution I have a SG.BannerModule project in which I just want to bind an Image in my BannerView.xaml.
I use the below BannerViewModel that implements IBannerViewModel because I am using containers to resolve my BannerViewModel.
Here is the IBannerViewModel interface:

```c#
public interface IBannerViewModel : IViewModel
{
    Uri BannerImageUri { get; set; }
}
```

I exposed the BannerImageUri because I am resolve the BannerViewModel thru the container in the
BannerMainModule using the Interface.

The BannerViewModel implementation is

```
public class BannerViewModel : ViewModelBase, IBannerViewModel
{

    #region Properties

    private IUnityContainer _container;
    private ILogger _logger;

    private Uri _bannerImageUri;
    public Uri BannerImageUri
    {
        get { return new Uri("pack://SG.Website:,,,SG.BannerModule;component/Assets/SGBanner2.png"); }
        set
        {
            if (value != _bannerImageUri)
            {
                _bannerImageUri = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("BannerImageUri");
            }

        }
    }

     #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public BannerViewModel(IBannerView bannerView, IUnityContainer container)
        : base(bannerView)
    {
        View = bannerView;
        View.ViewModel = this;

        _container = container;
        _logger = _container.Resolve<ILogger>();

        _logger.WriteToLogs("BannerViewModel Constructor");
    } 
    #endregion

 }
```

The Image is located in the Assets directory of my SG.BannerModule project.
I have set the build properties for the Image SGBanner2.png to be a resource and have added the image in the resources tab of the Properties Pane for the SG.BannerModule project.
I have set the data context of the BannerView.xaml in the BannerView.xaml.cs file in the following way because I am using View Injection.

```
public partial class BannerView : UserControl, IBannerView
{
    public BannerView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public IViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get 
        { 
            return (IBannerViewModel) DataContext; 
        }
        set { DataContext = value; }
    }

}
```

Because of the View First View Injection pattern I set the DataContext in my in code behind and do not set any in the XAML.

My question is

1. Because I am binding this image, do I need to use an ImageSource converter? If this is the case, will it be a problem because the image is a png and not a bitmap?
2. Or is the problem the Pack Uri.  Because I am using this module in a region in my SG.WebSite project, I am not sure that my pack Uri is correct but I have not been able to trouble shoot correctly why my image is not showing up in my shell window.
   Stumped?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so you know, it appears you are using ViewModel first.  Having your ViewModel resolve your View and then probably calling region.Add(viewModel.View).

This is the packURI syntax for local resource files:

pack://application:,,,/Subfolder/ResourceFile.xaml

For reference resource files:

pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/Subfolder/ResourceFile.xaml